# Google Sheet API : "message": "The request is missing a valid API key."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to make an extencion that will take some data from page and send it to google sheet. 
My manifest:

```
"oauth2": {
        "client_id": "client_id",
        "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"] 
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs", 
        "https://*.*/*",
        "storage",
        "declarativeContent",
        "identity",
        "https://ssl.gstatic.com/",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/*",
        "https://accounts.google.com/",
        "https://sheets.googleapis.com/",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets/"
    ],
    "key": {key}
```

background page:

```
var tokenS;
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({number: value}, function(data) {
  });
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
        interactive: false
    }, function(token) { 
        tokenS = token
        console.log(token)
    });
});
function writeData(request, sender){
    myspreadsheetId = "myspreadsheetId " 
    var params = {
        "range":"Sheet1!A1:A",
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": [
            [request.name]
        ],
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + myspreadsheetId + '/values/Sheet1!A1:A1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED');
    console.log(tokenS)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+tokenS);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
};
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(writeData)
```

I receive next error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

at google cloud platform I see a 100% error ratio (http://prntscr.com/jvfl0c). And I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. Pleasse help.

Comment: Well you API key seems to be invalid.

Comment: @ Liora Haydont as I know "There are two ways to identify your application: using an OAuth 2.0 token (which also authorizes the request) and/or using the application's API key."(https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)
I'm using OAuth2.0 everything should work.

Comment: Are you authenticated with [OAuth2.0](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tut_oauth#oauth_client) before making a request?

Comment: @nogui yes, I get token:
'chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
        interactive: false
    }, function(token) { 
        tokenS = token
        console.log(token)
    });' 
and then I use it: 
'xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+tokenS);'

Answer (score 3):

You're meant to replace the second 'key' in `"key": {key}`(on the last line of the first code sample) with an API Key you've generated for your project in the Google Cloud Console.
To Generate your API Key you need to navigate to the credentials page and click on **create credentials >> API key**.

---

Firstly, ensure that your project of choice is selected [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxTgC.jpg)

---

Next; from the 'Navigation Menu' >> 'APIs & Services' >> 'Crendentials' >> 'Create Credentials' >> 'API key'

Answer (score 0):

that is case sensitive
please check it whether it is Key or key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).